# Ignoring inner header rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am scraping multiple tables from the web that are exactly like [this one](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?id=abreuto01&t=b&year=2010) (the big batting gamelogs table) and I need the dataframe to ignore the inner header rows that start with the month of the season.

Here is my script so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib2

def stir_the_soup():
    player_links = open('player_links.txt', 'r')   
    player_ID_nums = open('player_ID_nums.txt', 'r')
    id_nums = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in player_ID_nums]
    idx = 0
    for url in player_links:
        #open the url and create bs object
        player_link = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(player_link, 'html5lib')

        #identify which table is needed
        table_id = ""
        if url[-12] == 'b':
            table_id = "batting"
        elif url[-12] == 'p':
            table_id = "pitching"

        #find the table and create dataframe
        table = str(bs.find('table', {'id' : (table_id + '_gamelogs')}))

        df = pd.read_html(table, header=0)
        df2 = df[0]
        df2 = df2[df2.PA != 'PA']

        #for the name of the file and file path
        file_path = '/Users/kramerbaseball/Desktop/MLB_Web_Scraping_Program/game_logs_non_concussed/'
        name_of_file = str(id_nums[idx])

        df2.to_csv(path_or_buf=(file_path + name_of_file + '.csv'), sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
        idx += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stir_the_soup()
```

I tried taking the dataframe and ignoring the rows where PA == PA or HR == HR but it will not delete the rows. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in some inner headers columns values are constant. This will drop intermediate headers from your `df`:

```
df3 = df2[df2['Gtm']!='Date']
```

Comment: thank you, this worked, but why is it where the 'Gtm' column != 'Date'? they are separate columns

Comment: No idea, but captain obvious supposes that columns and headers somehow moved one against another=)